# Cold Water not working in kitchen

Tags: kitchen-sink

Our kitchen faucet doesn’t have any cold water, the hot water works (same faucet). All other water faucets work fine. Not on an outside wall. When we let it trickle the water isn’t cold, mire tepid.

Answer (score 1):

If a single handle, remove and inspect the cartridge for blockage. If a double handle, remove the valve stem for the cold water and inspect for blockage. Then put a bowl or glass over the opening and have someone open your shutoff valve, which hopefully you closed before starting this, to make sure it opens correctly and isn't blocked. The problem should surface after doing all this.

Comment: When you open the shutoff valve - *do it very slowly!*. There can be a lot of pressure in the flow. Also remove the cold water valve very slowly. If the shutoff valve is faulty you may have water pressure behind it. Also - if this is a single handle be sure to shut off both hot and cold under the sink.

Comment: @HoneyDo  Great points.